# Get undefined reference when compiling C++ client for ZooKeeper

Tags: c++, apache-zookeeper

I try to compile my very first program in C++ in which I try to connect to ZooKeeper and do some other stuff. In my code I have these lines:

```
//test.cpp

#include "zookeeper.h"
... all other header files from zookeeper/include

void main_watcher (zhandle_t *zkh,
               int type,
               int state,
               const char *path,
               void* context)
{
    if(type == ZOO_SESSION_EVENT){
        if(state == ZOO_CONNECTED_STATE){
           ...
        }
        ...
    }
}

int main(){
   return 0;
}
```

But when I compile this `test.cpp` file (indeed, I provide link to the zookeeper/.../build/usr/lib and path to all included files), I get a list of these error messages:

```
undefined reference to ZOO_SESSION_EVENT
undefined reference to ZOO_CONNECTED_STATE
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not linking with Zookeeper library, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to **link** agains zookeeper, most probably. Typically, you'd have to do something like

```
g++ -lzookeper -o yourprogram yourprogram.c
```

maybe it's

```
-lzookeeper-mt
```

maybe not. Usually, it's job of a **build system** to figure these things out for you.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it in a second.

Comment: I tried `$ g++ -I path_to_include_folder -L path_to_lib_folder -lzookeper -o test test.cpp` and `$ g++ -I path_to_include_folder -L path_to_lib_folder -lzookeper-mt -o test test.cpp`, but still have the same error messages.

Comment: This looks as right - `$ g++ -I path_to_include_folder -L path_to_lib_folder -lzookeper_mt -o test test.cpp`. When I comment all constants like `ZOO_SESSION_EVENT`, then compilation runs smoothly. However, if I try to compile the initial program, I still see the same error messages.

Comment: Oh, it seems to work, if I comment `ZOO_NOTCONNECTED_STATE`. Whereas all other constants are ok. So, I think that `ZOO_NOTCONNECTED_STATE` has become deprecated.